# Проверка с помощью инструкции assert

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def calculate_multipl_negative_elements(n, numbers):
    if not isinstance(numbers, list) or numbers is []:
        return None
    mult = 1
    for element in numbers:
        if element < 0:
            mult *= element
    return mult


def main():
    n = 5
    numbers = [random.randint(-10, 10) for i in range(n)]
    msg = 'Our sequence : {}\nThe multiplication  of negative elements = {}'. \
    format(numbers, calculate_multipl_negative_elements(n, numbers))
    print(msg)


main()
```

Вопрос заключается в том, что нужно осуществить проверку с помощью инструкции assert, чтобы не надо было много раз тестировать(передавать пустой список, передавать не список). Принцип должен быть такой, но я не понимаю как это все организовать,чтобы проверка заработала, и я в принципе не очень понимаю логику всей этой конструкции ниже, но надо так 
Типо

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   assert calculate_multipl_negative_elements(n, []) is None, "Error calculate_multipl_negative_elements(n, []) "
   assert calculate_multipl_negative_elements(n, (1)) is None, "Error calculate_multipl_negative_elements(n, (1)) "
```

Comment: `assert (условие которое должно выполняться), (текст, который должен вывестись, если условие не выполнилось)` если совсем по-простому. Вторая часть необязательна.

Answer (score 0):

Логика тут простая. Есть предположение, которое не при каких обстоятельствах не будет ложным. Если вдруг это окажется не так, то сообщить об этом и завершить выполнение.

```
>>> assert 2*2 == 5, "думал, что 2*2=5, как оказалось - нет!"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: думал, что 2*2=5, как оказалось - нет!
```

В отличии от других ошибок, обрабатывать AssertionError не надо, потому что она вызвана изначально неверным предположением. Как в примере выше, надо посмотреть учебник арифметики за 1 кл., а не пытаться заполнить пробелы в образовании програмным путем.